# JSON manipulation in Node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have a JSON string: `[ { name: 'Bob' }, { name: 'Kim' }, { name: 'Jack' } ]` and I want to save all list of names in an array. Is there any proper way to do that rather than looping?

Comment: You can get information out of the string with a RegEx

Comment: This is not valid JSON. Please don't call just any JavaScript object JSON ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
[{name: 'Bob'}, {name: 'Kim'}, {name: 'Jack'}].map(function(x) {return x.name});
```

If it's a string, you need to call `JSON.parse()` before, like that:

```
var json = JSON.parse('[{"name": "Bob"}, {"name": "Kim"}, {"name": "Jack"}]');
var names = json.map(function(x) {return x.name});
```

Note that you have to use double quotes instead of apostrophes to make it a valid JSON string.

Comment: Don't forget that `map` will do the loop behind the scenes

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin I would wager that every Node.js script would involve looping in some way or another.

Answer (score 2):

Your string should look like this:

```
var str = '[{ "name": "Bob" }, { "name": "Kim" }, { "name": "Jack" } ]';
```

Then you can use:

```
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(str);
```

To extract the names use the function from [Gothdo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3853934/gothdo):

```
var names = jsonObj.map(function(x) {return x.name});
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qjn46u4z/4/

Comment: `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: It also works with plain javascript - edited my answer

Comment: @lightstalker89 how does this extract the names, though?

Comment: Yeah true - my fault. Wrong fiddle and missing explanation